# how to set custom viewcontroller's view as snapshot when iOS app enters in background mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to set viewcontroller's view as snapshot when app enters in background mode. When I go in background mode in portrait mode and then rotate my device to landscape mode and press Home button twice I don't see snapshot view in background mode. In some instances, the snapshot is cut off and I can see some portion of last page I visited.

below is my code

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //[application ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch];

    UIInterfaceOrientation orintation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]    statusBarOrientation];
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orintation))
{
    _tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    _tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
else
{
    _tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
    _tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

[UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.subviews.lastObject      addSubview:_tempView];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [_tempView removeFromSuperview];
    _tempView = nil;
}
```

Comment: i tried landscape on iphone 6 + , your code is fine

Comment: I am testing in iPad and it is not working as expected.

Comment: can u add the screenshot ?

Comment: Not enough reputation to share screenshot

Comment: use imgur and share the link

Comment: I print out view value and it is calculating width and height properly in landscape and portrait mode but in landscape mode X and Y value are in negative. Here is the out put : <UIView: 0x1688b560; frame = (-128 128; 1024 768); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1688b5f0>>

Comment: I resolved the issue long way back. Sorry I forget to update here. As I i still don't have enough reputation to share it but I will create sample app and share link here.